# Issue when trying to Deploy GWT web application in Jboss

Tags: gwt, jboss, noclassdeffounderror, gwt-mvp

I have a strange error I created a web application using gin,Presenter
and dispatcher and then I successfully deployed in JBoss but when I
trying to deploy in process server I followed the same way  by copying
war folder and including that application.xml which was running under
jboss I am getting error

Error configuring application listener of class
com.wellsfargo.coredevelopment.server.guice.MyGuiceServletConfig
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/inject/servlet/
GuiceServletContextListener
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:
141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:296)
    at
org.jboss.mx.loading.RepositoryClassLoader.loadClassLocally(RepositoryClassLoader.java:
190)
    at org.jboss.mx.loading.ClassLoadingTask
$ThreadTask.run(ClassLoadingTask.java:131)
    at org.jboss.mx.loading.LoadMgr3.nextTask(LoadMgr3.java:399)
    at
org.jboss.mx.loading.RepositoryClassLoader.loadClassImpl(RepositoryClassLoader.java:
517)
    at
org.jboss.mx.loading.RepositoryClassLoader.loadClass(RepositoryClassLoader.java:
405)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:296)
    at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(URLClassLoader.java:627)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:296)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:
3711)
    at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:
4211)
    at
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:
759)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:
739)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:
524)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:
39)
    at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:
25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at
org.apache.commons.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:
503)
    at
org.jboss.mx.server.RawDynamicInvoker.invoke(RawDynamicInvoker.java:
164)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:
659)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.init(StandardContext.java:
5052)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:
39)
    at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:
25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at
org.apache.commons.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:
503)
    at
org.jboss.mx.server.RawDynamicInvoker.invoke(RawDynamicInvoker.java:
164)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:
659)
    at
org.jboss.web.tomcat.tc5.TomcatDeployer.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployer.java:
297)
    at
org.jboss.web.tomcat.tc5.TomcatDeployer.performDeploy(TomcatDeployer.java:
103)
    at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebDeployer.start(AbstractWebDeployer.java:
371)
    at org.jboss.web.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:83)
    at org.jboss.web.WebModule.startService(WebModule.java:61)
    at
org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:
289)
    at
org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:
245)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor11.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:
25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at
org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:
155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
    at
org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:
264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:
659)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController
$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
    at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:
417)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor17.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:
25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at
org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:
155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
    at
org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:
264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:
659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at $Proxy29.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebContainer.start(AbstractWebContainer.java:
466)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:
39)
    at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:
25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at
org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:
155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at
org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:
133)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at
org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:
142)
    at
org.jboss.mx.interceptor.DynamicInterceptor.invoke(DynamicInterceptor.java:
97)
    at
org.jboss.system.InterceptorServiceMBeanSupport.invokeNext(InterceptorServiceMBeanSupport.java:
238)
    at
org.jboss.ws.integration.jboss.DeployerInterceptor.start(DeployerInterceptor.java:
92)
    at org.jboss.deployment.SubDeployerInterceptorSupport
$XMBeanInterceptor.start(SubDeployerInterceptorSupport.java:188)
    at
org.jboss.deployment.SubDeployerInterceptor.invoke(SubDeployerInterceptor.java:
95)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at
org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:
264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:
659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at $Proxy30.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1015)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor55.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:
25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at
org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:
155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at
org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:
133)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at
org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:
142)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at
org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:
264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:
659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at $Proxy9.deploy(Unknown Source)
    at
org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.deploy(URLDeploymentScanner.java:
421)
    at
org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.scan(URLDeploymentScanner.java:
634)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner
$ScannerThread.doScan(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:263)
    at
org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner.startService(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:
336)
    at
org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:
289)
    at
org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:
245)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor11.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:
25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at
org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:
155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
    at
org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:
264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:
659)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController
$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
    at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:
417)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor17.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:
25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at
org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:
155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
    at
org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:
264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:
659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at $Proxy4.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer.start(SARDeployer.java:302)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:766)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:
39)
    at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:
25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at
org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:
155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at
org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:
133)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at
org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:
142)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at
org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:
264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:
659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at $Proxy5.deploy(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java:482)
    at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:362)
    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:200)
    at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:490)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceServletContextListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)

The jar folders in my lib are
aopalliance.jar
gin.jar
guice-2.0.jar
guice-servlet-2.0.jar
gwt-dispatch-1.0.0-snapshot.jar
gwt-log-2.6.2.jar
gwt-presenter-1.0.0-snapshot.jar
gwt-servlet.jar

I tested with the samle application of greeting provided by google and
it got deployed successfully in my process server....

and the class structure is

import com.google.inject.Guice;
import com.google.inject.Injector;
import com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceServletContextListener;

public class MyGuiceServletConfig extends GuiceServletContextListener
{

```
@Override
protected Injector getInjector() {
    return Guice.createInjector(new ServerModule(), new
```

DispatchServletModule());
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure that the classes you listed are actually either

- in the war files WEB-INF/lib/ folder
- or in the lib folder of the appservers instance (e.g.
  server/default/lib ) ?